# What is necessary to implement HTTPS?

Tags: security, https

I'm an iPhone Developer and I've recently got into web development. At the moment I have two sites on the internet, and on one of them, I have a very simplistic CMS I've made.

Firstly, do I need to implement HTTPS for this?

If so, is there a good tutorial on getting started with this? What steps do I need to set this up?

Comment: why is it neccessary to send data over an encrypted connection so it is safe from eavesdropping?

Comment: HTTPS, _Secured_ hypertext transfer protocol, has nothing to do with your application layer. Please read on HTTPS before trying to use it.

Comment: I have one user for the CMS (apart from myself) and it's a really low-traffic brochure site - is it necessary?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your hosting provider supports https (SSL). You should be able to generate or upload your own certificate using their admin panel.

Answer (score 2):

The SSL/TLS protocol implementation on server side has to be done in the web-server - usually Apache HTTPD.

Therefore enabling HTTPS is totally independent of PHP. You should check the documentation of the used web-server.

Answer (score 0):

Think about this:

In early days, the receptionist would you give a **safe box** at the **hotel's safe box room** to put your valuable stuff there and you also would get **a key** to open that box.

When you would go to that box latter to open it, you would realize that **two keys are required to open that box**. One is your key and the other one is at the reception. **One of them is never enough**. You would need both to open it.

That's exactly what is happening for `SSL` either. If you transfer valuable (sensitive) data back and forth between your browser and server, you need SSL.